# String array in TreeView item

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

I have a TreeView bound to an `ObservableCollection` of items, defined as such (full example View Model provided for completeness):

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace ViewModels
{
    public class MainViewModel()
    {
        public ObservableCollection<CustomTask> SavedTasks { get; } = new ObservableCollection<CustomTask>();

        public MainViewModel() {}
    }

    public class CustomTask
    {
        public string DisplayName { get; private set; }
        public string Name { get; private set; }
        public string[] Tasks { get; private set; }

        public CustomTask(string dispName, string name, string[] tasks)
        {
            DisplayName = dispName;
            Name = name;
            Tasks = tasks;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to display each `CustomTask` object in a tree view with its `Tasks` property being the children in the tree view. I've read some online tutorials and such and can't get the strings to display. This is the XAML I have so far:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding SavedTasks}">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type common:CustomTask}" ItemsSource="{Binding SavedTasks}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type sys:String}" ItemsSource="{Binding Tasks}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

I'm not sure what to do with the second DataTemplate. I'm hoping to avoid creating another class just to hold each string in the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you are looking for:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding SavedTasks}">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:CustomTask}" ItemsSource="{Binding Tasks}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type sys:String}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

We add the `HierarchicalDataTemplate` with the `ItemsSource` bound to the `Tasks` property of each node.

We define that each root node should use a `TextBlock` showing each item's `Name` property.

And then we define how the children should look like with a `DataTemplate`. We don't need another `HierarchicalDataTemplate`, because we only have two levels.